# What file types could possibly be a worm or contain a viral infection

Tags: virus, file-extension, file-types

On Windows what file extensions do you have to look out for concerning viruses/worms? I ask because I'm wondering if there's a point in scanning .cfm files.

Comment: Well even the `.docx` can be one of them, so its good to keep antivirus do his own work.. :)

Comment: A file extension is just an arbitrary label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any exploitable executable could become a vector for infection. Since you can't really know ahead of time which apps are exploitable...

Answer (score 0):

Because of stack overflow and such bugs in the software, any data file with a buggy data reader can be an attack vector. It does not need to be an executable.

This goes for image files, font files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is that viruses/worms may make use of files with all sorts of extensions, either just as a place to hide themselves, or as a vector for infection. On the server side, there are certainly cases of infections [hiding within files with .cfm extensions](https://badwarebusters.org/main/itemview/5298).